# Property tokenised set false not works

Tags: alfresco

I change property by adding `tokenised` as follows:

```
<property name="sci:doc">
 <type>d:text</type>
 <index enabled="true"> 
   <atomic>true</atomic> 
   <stored>false</stored> 
   <tokenised>false</tokenised> 
 </index>
</property>
```

After fully rebuilding the index and restarting alfresco I searched in node browser using Lucene like this:

```
PATH:"/app:company_home/app:guest_home/cm:mySpace/*" AND (@sci\:doc:'my doc')
```

But no result was returned. I also tried `(@sci\:doc:'my') OR (@sci\:doc:'doc')`. This all failed.

I'm using 3.4.d. I found any property that sets `<tokenised>` to false has this issue: Search always returns nothing!

I tried alfresco-fts search in node browser, it works for the `tokenized` property above, but I'm using Alfresco web service, the default `QUERY_LANG_LUCENE` is `lucene`. I cannot switch to alfresco-fts.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why the old version of Alfresco?

Comment: That's strange, it should work. And it has done something, because my  and doc aren't been shown any more.
Have you tried with 'my*' or just :my*. Also try to add content with just my in the field to test if it's even being indexed well.

Comment: yeah! I tried below query both work, PATH:"/app:company_home/app:guest_home/cm:mySpace/*" AND (@sci\:doc:my*doc)  
PATH:"/app:company_home/app:guest_home/cm:mySpace/*" AND (@sci\:doc:my\ doc)    but i really dont' know the syntax of lucene, thanks!